# how to set fetch-size for a query in clojure jdbc?

Tags: jdbc, clojure

In the clojure jdbc file of https://github.com/clojure/java.jdbc/blob/master/src/main/clojure/clojure/java/jdbc.clj
we could set fetch size for function of prepare-statement. But it's very often to just query a large table and also need to set the fetch size. Won't it better to also provide an option to the function of "query"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `query` function used to allow options to be passed through to the `prepare-statement` call as part of the "SQL & params" vector but it was not well-documented:

```
(query [{:fetch-size 50} "SELECT * FROM students WHERE age = ?" 24])
```

As of java.jdbc 0.6.0-rc2, `prepare-statement` options can be passed in the normal options map position:

```
(query ["SELECT * FROM students WHERE age = ?" 24] {:fetch-size 50})
```

The older way, above, will work on versions prior to 0.6.0-rc2 but is no longer supported (it will throw an exception). See http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/JDBC-125 for more details.

Comment: I updated this answer to reflect the changes introduced in release 0.6.0-rc2.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand you correctly, you would like to set the maximum number of rows that are returned  from a query. In that case, you can use `LIMIT`, like this

```
(clojure.java.jdbc/query
 ["SELECT * FROM students WHERE age = 24 ORDER BY created LIMIT 50"])
```

This should be helpful:
[Clojure and Large Result Sets](http://asymmetrical-view.com/2010/10/14/clojure-and-large-result-sets.html)

Comment: @daniel-wu is asking about the `:fetch-size` option for `prepare-statement`, used to construct a PreparedStatement object internally, rather than just limiting the number of rows returned.